# Decrypt at rest data in Redshift

Tags: encryption, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, amazon-kms

I'm loading data from dynamoDB to redshift database. Some columns that contain sensitive information are encrypted with AWS KMS. I need to decrypt these column values in redshift and load the decrypted values into a different/new redshift table. How can I get this done in redshift?

I haven't found any information online on how to accomplish this task in redshift.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What have you tried? Do you have any code to share or things you set up to move the data like AWS DMS?

Comment: I haven't tried anything for decryption yet. Data is already in RedShift, some columns are encrypted with an AWS kms key, I need to create a udf in redshift (probably python coded) that I can call to decrypt the columns that are encrypted, in a sql query.